# Calculating days between dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I store certain dates of events in an array, of up to 7 elements, where the first element gets deleted if an 8th element needs to be added.

I format them as such: `9th Jan 2021`.

I've been struggling with finding a solution to this problem:

If an event hasn't been added in the previous day, I need to add this event anyway.

**Example**: if a user sets an event on the `9th Jan 2021`, and the most recent has been on the `30th Dec 2020`, I need to add the most recent `7` days to the array, as the gap is over a week. If the gap isn't over a week, I just need to add whatever dates are in between, e.g. `9th Jan 2021` and `5th Jan 2021`.

At an event update on `12th Jan 2021` such that the array = `["29th Dec 2020", "30th Dec 2020", ... , "4th Jan 2021"]`, the array needs to be set to `[]`, then set to: `["6th Jan 2021", ... , "12th Jan 2021"]`.

I have tried writing very long algorithms for this, but just keep running into so many errors that I figured there has to be an easier way to do this.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly do NOT calculate on the format you display. Please show the code you tried if it is not like the dupe. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by setting the array to [] and then something else. Please give input and exact expected output. Sounds to me you can just make an array of 14 days and then slice it to fit